# Changer SetInterval Values After Interval

Tags: javascript, intervals

If I can try to make everyone understand what I am looking for, I am looking for the value of the interval to change to lets say "5000ms" after "1000ms" and then it would go on to the next value such as "2000ms" and repeat all over again! The current code I have is pretty much a stopwatch, It adds the number 1 to a paragraph every 1000ms. Any help is extremely appreciated!

```html
<script>
function myFunction() {
    clicks += 1;
}
setInterval(myFunction, 1000);
     var clicks = 0;
    function myFunction() {

        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = clicks; 
// connects to paragraph id
    }
</script>
<p id="demo"></p>
<!--connects to getElementById-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `setInterval` - this functions will perform the action in any given interval, which you set once.

Use `setTimeout` instead. Which performs the action only once after given interval, and then call it again and again with different interval values.

Answer (score 0):

what about this

```
<script>
var clicks = 0;
myFunction(1000);
function myFunction( currentInterval ) {
    clicks ++;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = clicks; 
    if ( currentInterval == 1000 )
    {
        currentInterval = 5000;
    }
    else if ( currentInterval == 5000 )
    {
        currentInterval = 2000;
    }
    else
    {
        currentInterval = 1000;
    }
    setTimeout( function(){ myFunction( currentInterval ) }, currentInterval );
}
</script>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try using recursive timeout instead of interval

```js
var timeout = 1000;

var timer;

function startTimer() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('tick');
    startTimer();
  }, timeout);
}
startTimer();

// timeout = 2000
// timeout = 500
// clearTimeout(timer); to cancel
```

```html
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might look a little complicated but you can try something like this:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/461pg67a/).

```js
(function() {
  var interval = null;
  var limit = 5;

  function initInterval(callback, index) {
    var msToSec = 1000;
    if (interval) {
      clearInterval();
    }
    console.log("Delay: ", index)
    interval = setInterval(callback, index * msToSec);
  }

  function clearInterval() {
    window.clearInterval(interval);
    interval = null;
  }

  function resetInterval(callback, count) {
    clearInterval();
    initInterval(callback, count);
  }

  function main() {
    var count = 1;

    var notify = function() {
      console.log("Hello World: ", count);
      var _nextCount = ((count++) % limit) + 1;
      if (count < 10) {
        resetInterval(notify, _nextCount);
      } else {
        console.log("Stoping loop...");
        clearInterval();
      }

    }

    initInterval(notify, count);
  }

  main()
})()
```